# Why doesn't STL "officially" support std::string to std::wstring conversions?

Tags: c++, string

I am aware that `std::string` and `std::wstring` come from the same base type `std::basic_string<>`. But there isn't an "official" way to convert `std::string` data to `std::wstring` using the C++ STL? I mean Windows provide `MultiByteToWideChar()` to convert but why cant the STL provide one?

I used `std::codecvt` before to get it done but now it says that it is deprecated. Why does the STL remove this support the first place?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::wstring my_wide_string{narrow_string.begin(), narrow_string.end()};`?

Comment: @NathanOliver that approach *works* only for ASCII characters, it will not convert non-ASCII characters properly

Comment: @RemyLebeau actually it should work for the Latin-1 character set, of which ASCII is a subset. That still excludes a huge proportion of the world's characters so +1 for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *character encoding* of `std::string` is not defined by the C++ standard, a `std::string` can hold any encoding that can be represented using 1-byte `char` elements, which includes UTF-7/8, ISO-8859-x, Windows-125x, etc.

Also, the size of `wchar_t` is *implementation-defined*, not defined by the standard, so even the *encoding* of `std::wstring` can vary, too.  On Windows, `wchar_t` is 2 bytes, so `std::wstring` uses UCS-2/UTF-16 encoding.  Whereas on other platforms, `wchar_t` is 4 bytes, so `std::wstring` uses UCS-4/UTF-32.

So, there is no single conversion that satisfies all possible combinations of `std::string <-> std::wstring` conversions across all platforms and use-cases.  So, you need to know the encoding of the source string, and the intended encoding of the target string, in order to perform a conversion.

And yes, the C++ standard did provide `std::codecvt` and `std::wstring_convert`/`std::wbuffer_convert` for this task, but they have been deprecated, as you have noted.  There is no *standard* replacement provided (yet?).

So, you are best off using 3rd party Unicode API/libraries to handle character conversions.

Comment: [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/home) is one good one.  (Better than reinventing that particular wheel.)

Comment: The problem with this answer seems to be that the C++ standard, having left both encodings to the implementation, could simply define that an implementation-defined conversion exists. It might even be reasonable to state that the characters in the basic set will round-trip.

Comment: @MSalters except that the `std::string` encoding is not *implementation*-defined, it is *user*-defined. I guess the same could be said of `std::wstring`, but since it is using an *implementation*-defined character type, that limits the encodings the user could choose to use. I mean, you *can* store UTF-8 units as-is into a `std::wstring`, but why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I'd assume the `std::string` encoding is just the `char` encoding, given that it's `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>>`. You can a `basic_string` with other traits, but that wouldn't be `std::string`.  The encoding of `char c='a';` is not user-defined, is it? How would it be? I don't even recall "user-defined" in the list "defined by standard, implementation defined, unspecified, undefined".

Comment: @MSalters there's nothing in the standard that prevents `char` from holding [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) for example.

Comment: @MSalters any 7/8-bit encoding can be stored in a `std::string`, and the standard library would have no knowledge of which encoding were being used. Just arbitrary `char` values that would mean different things in different contexts. That is why I say it is *user*-defined